# Different way to ask a question

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Let’s say that my friend saw a mouse in the house . After catching it would it be grammatically correct if he said sentences below  ;

> Do you think there is any of it ?
>
> Do you think there is one more of it ?
>
> Do you think there is any other of it ?

If  all of them are incorrect , what should I say by using “it”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be correct if "of it" refers to "mice".  Mice is plural and so the pronoun should be plural too.

> Do you think there are any more of them?
>
> Do you think there are any others?

It is not a grammatical error if "it" refers to one mouse, but in this context you wouldn't ask "Do you think that there is exactly one more mouse?" And for an indeterminate number, the plural is used.